# Numpy array instead of float

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've written a simple function

```
def rect(t):
    field = np.zeros((len(t),3))
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] >=-10 and t[i] <=10:
            field[i,1] = 1
        else:
            field[i,1] = 0
    return field
```

and want to integrate it

```
from scipy import integrate

def S_elem(t):
    return rect(t)[:,1]*integr

integrate.quad(S_elem, -10, 10)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I know I may not use numpy array but I need it for the other purpose. How can I
perform integration without the removal of the numpy array type?

Comment: Another thing that isn't completely clear is what `integr` is in your `S_elem` function

Comment: Integr is merely a variable that dreams to be a function in the future) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your float to a numpy array:

```
def rect(t):
    t = np.atleast_1d(t)
    field = np.zeros((len(t), 3))
    field[:, 1] = abs(t) <= 10
    return field
```